# Error -> 403 Request Forbidden by administrative rules

Tags: php, deployment, virtual-machine, subdomain, domain-name

Hi I have my php code up and running on a server. When I enter the below url in the  browser i get the content .

```
<ip_address_vm>/service.php
```

I have purchased a domain name from goDaddy and linked the domain to the ip address of the vm. But now,when i enter the below url in the browser

```
domain_name/service.php
```

I get ->

```
403 Forbidden
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
```

I dont have the administrator rights to the vm, but i can access this vm. Can someone help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: is the missing 'v' in `serice.php` a typo in the question or could it be related to the problem? Also you must ensure the webserver handle's the domain name properly inside it's configuration.

Comment: 'serice.php' is a typo. updating the question

Comment: Then check the webserver configuration. Also check the error logs to see what exactly causes the 403. You might even want to ensure your dns already gives you the correct IP for the domain.